# Magento function getMessages - how to detect if messages has been set

Tags: magento

does anyone know how to detect it messages has been set?

I found the following in core/session:

```
public function getMessages($clear=false)
```

But how do I now check if there is a message, or not?

(we use it to invalidate cache)

Comment: Maybe i didn't understand the question but what about a count() on it ?

Comment: agree with Bixi, what exactly do you want to get, if you already know how to retrieve messages?

Comment: Take a look @ app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Messages.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Bixi

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMessages()->count()
```

IF > 0 we invalidate our FP Cache (or block)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the storage for each session namespace (catalog, checkout, core, customer, tag...) for the presence of messages. EE observes the `core_session_abstract_add_message` event and writes a cookie which can then be referenced to determine whether there are messages to display. If you are authorized, refer to `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Messages`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMessages();
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but there are multiple session namespaces.

Comment: But i think on this case its this one.